# Combining Queries

Tags: mysql

trying to save a step and combine these two queries but not sure how to go about it best. Basically the first query is getting the list of reviews in our system and the second one is seeing if a notification has been sent (if there are results returned then it has been sent).

get reviews:

```
SELECT r.*, 
    coalesce( ( SELECT AVG(rr.rating) 
                FROM `" . DBTABLEPREFIX . "reviews_ratings` rr 
                WHERE rr.review_id = r.id
              )
            , ''
            ) AS rating,
    FROM `" . DBTABLEPREFIX . "reviews` r
    WHERE BELOW SELECT IS 0 RESULTS
```

check if notification exists (yes I know this doesn't work by itself):

```
SELECT rn.* 
FROM `" . DBTABLEPREFIX . "reviews_notifications` rn 
WHERE rn.website_id = r.website_id 
  AND rn.post_id = r.post_id
```

Any ideas on the way to do this properly? Also in case you are wondering why we can't check r.id on the notifications table its because the reviews and reviews_ratings table are cleared each day with fresh data. The process will probably be rewritten later to not kill but only add new items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery, using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT r.*, 
    coalesce( ( SELECT AVG(rr.rating) 
                FROM `" . DBTABLEPREFIX . "reviews_ratings` rr 
                WHERE rr.review_id = r.id
              )
            , ''
            ) AS rating,
    FROM `" . DBTABLEPREFIX . "reviews` r
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
          ( SELECT rn.* 
            FROM `" . DBTABLEPREFIX . "reviews_notifications` rn 
            WHERE rn.website_id = r.website_id 
              AND rn.post_id = r.post_id
          )
```

The other subquery can be moved into the `FROM` part:

```
SELECT 
    r.*, 
    coalesce( rr.rating, '' ) AS rating,
FROM `" . DBTABLEPREFIX . "reviews` r
    LEFT JOIN
        ( SELECT
              rr.review_id, 
              AVG(rr.rating) AS rating
          FROM `" . DBTABLEPREFIX . "reviews_ratings` rr 
          GROUP BY rr.review_id
        ) AS rr
      ON rr.review_id = r.id     
WHERE NOT EXISTS
      ( SELECT rn.* 
        FROM `" . DBTABLEPREFIX . "reviews_notifications` rn 
        WHERE rn.website_id = r.website_id 
          AND rn.post_id = r.post_id
      )
```

Comment: By doing the second one instead of coalesce how much does that increase efficiency? It looks like perhaps the query gets run only once instead of every time like in my query.

Comment: You can test it off course. But the 2nd writing means that a derived table will be calculated first (with results after the group by) and this derived table will be join to the reviews table.

Comment: The inline query (like yours) may be run for every row of the review. It doesn't mean that it will be slower, that depends on a lot of factors. But it's usually slower. And consider if you want to also calculate a sum, besides the average. The engine will have to run 2 subqueries for every row in the review table.

Comment: Thanks I will definitely keep that in mind for future queries.